# Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch on combo box with alphanumeric data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to setup an update data entry form. How can I transition from integer combo box with only numerical values to a data type using string or long combo box with alphanumeric values?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Details")
Dim i As Integer

Me.UsernameComboBox.Clear
Me.UsernameComboBox.AddItem ""

For i = 11 To sh.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Me.UsernameComboBox.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i).Value
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub UsernameComboBox_Change()

If Me.UsernameComboBox <> "" Then

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Details")
    Dim i As Integer

    i = Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.UsernameComboBox.Value), sh.Range("B:B"), 0)

    Me.NameTextBox = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    Me.EmailTextBox = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
    Me.BirthdateTextBox = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
    Me.NationalIDTextBox = sh.Range("E" & i).Value
    Me.EmpIDTextBox = sh.Range("R" & i).Value
    Me.DeptTextBox = sh.Range("V" & i).Value

    If sh.Range("Y" & i).Value = "Male" Then Me.MaleOptionButton.Value = True
    If sh.Range("Y" & i).Value = "Female" Then Me.FemaleOptionButton.Value = True

    Me.StatusComboBox = sh.Range("X" & i).Value
    Me.CitizenshipComboBox = sh.Range("Z" & i).Value
    Me.EthnicityComboBox = sh.Range("F" & i).Value

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the run time error 13. Is it the line `i = Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.UsernameComboBox.Value), sh.Range("B:B"), 0)`?

Comment: Yup thats exactly where i get the run time error. How were you able to tell?

Comment: Because `Application.Match` wil return an error if it does not find a match based on the chocie you made in the combobox. You have to cover that in your code. Or even worse `Me.UsernameComboBox.Value` is not a number and you probably need to use `Me.UsernameComboBox.ListIndex` instead of `Me.UsernameComboBox.Value`

Comment: Yeah in the new excel template im trying to setup Me.UsernameComboBox.Value is in alphanumeric or text values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Assuming you do want not to change the numeric values in column B to Text or use another column with formula `=Text(B11,"#")`, it may be easy to use workaround `Find`. May try

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FndRng As Range, c As Range

    'i = Application.Match(Me.UsernameComboBox.Value, Sh.Range("B:B"), 0)
    Set FndRng = Sh.Range("B11:B" & Sh.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set c = FndRng.Find(Me.UsernameComboBox.Value, , LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        i = c.Row
        Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much for your help! The values in column B are actually in text for the new excel template I'm trying to setup.